# I am making a discord.js bot and I want to know if there was an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am using the following code to figure out if there was an error. But I want to not run something if there was an error. I have tried to look it up and I could not find anything about it.

```js
 member.roles.remove(role).catch((error) => {
    message.reply("I don't have permission to do that!");
});
message.channel.send("Removed role!");
```

Comment: Please provide more code because based on what you have posted the only thing that could be an issue is putting `message.member.roles.remove` instead of `member.roles.remove`. Can’t verify if member is defined. But please provide enough code to reproduce your issue

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this-

```
member.roles.remove(role).then(() => message.channel.send("Role Removed")).catch(err => message.channel.send("I dont have perms."))
```

If there will be an error it will not run the code inside .then().

Answer (score -1):

You can use a variable to accomplish this.

If there was an error, set the variable to true; else, the variable will remain false.

For your case:

```
let isError = false;
await member.roles.remove(role).catch((error) => {
    message.reply("I don't have permission to do that!");
    isError = true;
});
if(!isError){
    message.channel.send("Removed role!");
}
```

Comment: `async` methods (like `remove()`) don't work like that. By the time you check `if(!isError)`, the callback function inside your `catch` won't even run. `isError` will be `false` even if there is an error.

Comment: I edited my answer to include an `await`